# Install Python package from .py file

Tags: python, installation, package

Can I install the following .py file so that I can import this using the following command?

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/pytorchfundamentals/main/computer-vision-pytorch/pytorchcv.py

import pytorchcv
```

- The above file is different from pytorchcv package in PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import httpimport
with httpimport.remote_repo(['pytorchcv'], 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/pytorchfundamentals/main/computer-vision-pytorch/'):
    import pytorchcv
```